# Passing a viewmodel object to a jquery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to access the members of viewmodel object in a javascript function and have tried to do this by assigning it to a jscript variable like this:

```
var teamEdit = (function() {
                return {
                    communityGroups: '@Model.CommunityGroups'
                }
            });


$(function() {
....
 var groups = teamEdit.communityGroups;
```

Unfortunately the groups variable comes out as undefined even though 'CommunityGroups' is defintely populated. (checked by debugging controller)

Comment: What is the type of `CommunityGroups`?

Comment: try this https://dotnetfiddle.net/BG6sQl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Model.CommunityGroups` would simply call `ToString()` that would emit something like "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CommunityGroup]".

You need to serialize it to JSON instead:

```
communityGroups: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CommunityGroups))
```

Comment: Thank you haim, between you and KishoreSaha it's now working! :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code was you were try to access the function `teamEdit` with out `()` change it to `teamEdit()`

See the below.

```
var teamEdit = (function() {
                return {
                    communityGroups: '@Model.CommunityGroups'
                }
            });


$(function() {
....
 var groups = teamEdit().communityGroups;
```

Comment: Nice catch. Missed that.

Comment: great catch indeed, thank you!  However I still had a problem which was illustrated by haim below.